# mern api route with axios

Tags: api, mern

we are making an app using mern that will populate the page with what ever wine you search for.  But i cant get my api route to work.

```
    loadWines = () => {
      Axios.get("https://services.wine.com/?t=" + wineName + "&y=&apikey=05bd3e5306d43d741a06a939c5ea3dd27eaad377" + this.state.value)
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          value: '',
          isLoaded:true,
          Wines:json,
        })
      });
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState ({value: event.target.value});
    }
      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        Axios.get("https://services.wine.com/?t=" + wineName + "&y=&apikey=05bd3e5306d43d741a06a939c5ea3dd27eaad377" + this.state.value)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.setState({
            value: '',
            isLoaded:true,
            Wines:json,
          })
        });
        console.log(this.state.value)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think axios does returns json data, no need to convert to JSON,

fetch method does returns promise then we definitely need to convert it into `res.json()`

try this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

function(){
  axios.get(url).then(res=>{
    this.setState({data: res})
  })
}
```

let me know there is anything more. Happy coding